# How to programmatically add UITableView into UIStackView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uistackview

I created this code to test tableViews inside UIStackViews:

This is the `tableView` file:

```
import UIKit

class Table: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var items:[String] = ["alpha", "betha", "gama", "delta"]

    lazy var tableView:UITableView = {
        let tb = UITableView(frame: self.view.bounds, style: .grouped)
        tb.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        tb.delegate = self
        tb.dataSource = self
        tb.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier:"cell")
        return tb
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let item = self.items[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).item]
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(item)"
        return cell
    }
}
```

And this is my `MainViewController` with `Stack` and `tableView`:

```
import UIKit

class Main: UIViewController {

    lazy var table:Table = { return Table() }()

    lazy var mainStack: UIStackView = {
        let s = UIStackView()
        s.axis = .vertical
        s.alignment = .center
        s.distribution = .equalCentering
        s.spacing = 0
        s.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        s.addArrangedSubview(UIView())
        s.addArrangedSubview(self.table.view)
        s.addArrangedSubview(UIView())
        return s

    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(self.mainStack)
    }

}
```

In my delegate, if I use the Table class as rootViewController, everything works fine:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let table = Table()
        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: table)
        self.window!.rootViewController = nav
        self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
```

But, If I use the main class nothing is shown:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let main = Main()
        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: main)
        self.window!.rootViewController = nav
        self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Why would you want to put a table view in a stack view?

Comment: Hi matt, I'm thinking about create a dashboard with several different components and one of those is the tableView. Do you think this is not a good idea (put tableview into stackview)?

Comment: Stack view is a constraint-maker. It is for when you have several self-sizing views in a row or column and you need them to space themselves out in a way that would be complicated if you had to make the constraints yourself. This doesn't seem like that. For one thing, a table view is not self-sizing so it's hard to see how it's going to make sense in a stack view. Also, you haven't said anything about this being hard to do with making the constraints yourself.

Comment: You may need a height constraint on the table view. Try `tb.addConstraint(tb.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100))`.